# Gridlayout not rendering exact view on device

Tags: android, xml

using the xml to arrange items in rows and column using gridlayout:

```
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:alignmentMode="alignBounds"
    android:columnCount="4"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:rowCount="4"
    android:useDefaultMargins="true">

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_column="0"
    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_row="0"
    android:gravity="end"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="6dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:text="1"
        android:textColor="#424242"
        android:textSize="32sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/suptext1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:text="ABC"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textColor="#828282"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_column="1"
    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_row="0"
    android:gravity="end"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="6dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:text="1"
        android:textColor="#424242"
        android:textSize="32sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/suptext2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:text="ABC"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textColor="#828282"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />


</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_column="2"
    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_row="0"
    android:gravity="end"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="6dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:text="1"
        android:textColor="#424242"
        android:textSize="32sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/suptext3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:text="ABC"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textColor="#828282"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />


</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_column="3"
    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_row="0"
    android:gravity="end"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="6dp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:textColor="#424242"
        android:textSize="32sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <ImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/keybutton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_shuffle_black_24dp" />

</LinearLayout>


<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_column="0"
    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_row="1"
    android:gravity="end"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="6dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text21"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:text="1"
        android:textColor="#424242"
        android:textSize="32sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/suptext21"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:text="ABC"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textColor="#828282"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_column="1"
    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_row="1"
    android:gravity="end"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="6dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text22"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:text="1"
        android:textColor="#424242"
        android:textSize="32sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/suptext22"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:text="ABC"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textColor="#828282"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />


</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_column="2"
    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_row="1"
    android:gravity="end"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="6dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text23"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:text="1"
        android:textColor="#424242"
        android:textSize="32sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/suptext23"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:text="ABC"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textColor="#828282"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />


</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_column="3"
    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_row="1"
    android:gravity="end"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="6dp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:textColor="#424242"
        android:textSize="32sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <ImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/keybutton2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_close_black_24dp" />

</LinearLayout>


<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_column="0"
    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_row="2"
    android:gravity="end"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="6dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text31"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:text="1"
        android:textColor="#424242"
        android:textSize="32sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/suptext31"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:text="ABC"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textColor="#828282"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_column="1"
    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_row="2"
    android:gravity="end"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="6dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text32"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:text="1"
        android:textColor="#424242"
        android:textSize="32sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/suptext32"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:text="ABC"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textColor="#828282"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />


</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_column="2"
    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_row="2"
    android:gravity="end"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="6dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text33"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:text="1"
        android:textColor="#424242"
        android:textSize="32sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/suptext33"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:text="ABC"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textColor="#828282"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />


</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_column="3"
    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_row="2"
    android:gravity="end"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="6dp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:textColor="#424242"
        android:textSize="32sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <ImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/keybutton3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_keyboard_backspace_black_24dp" />

</LinearLayout>


<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:gravity="end"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="6dp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:textColor="#424242"
        android:textSize="32sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textColor="#828282"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:gravity="end"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="6dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text42"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:text="1"
        android:textColor="#424242"
        android:textSize="32sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/suptext42"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:text="ABC"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textColor="#828282"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />


</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:gravity="end"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="6dp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:textColor="#424242"
        android:textSize="32sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textColor="#828282"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />


</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:gravity="end"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="6dp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:textColor="#424242"
        android:textSize="32sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <ImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/keybutton4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_check_black_24dp" />

</LinearLayout>


</GridLayout>
```

it shows on android studio as:

[image: this] .

But when i run, i see something like:

[image: this] .

Entirely different from what i can see on android. How can i fix this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check the SDK level/version of the AVD and the app you're compiling. The AVD is same or higher than the app you're compiling.